# Getting a EXC_BAD_access if I don't put a breakpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am getting a EXC_BAD_access on this code

```
_emailID  = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.txtEmail.text];
_password = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.txtPassword.text];
 NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : _emailID, @"password" : _password, @"device" : @"iOS"};
```

I've enabled Zombie mode and this is what I get

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error

But when I put a breakpoint on the _emailID line and go to the next lines manually it doesn't throw an error at all

```
//View.h
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableString *emailID;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableString *password;

//View.m
@synthesize emailID;
@synthesize password;
```

Comment: Could it be that `self.txtEmail.text` is `nil`?  If so the `stringWithString:` function is crashing.  I would expect it to crash regardless of whether you have a breakpoint or not in that case, but at least rule that out.

Comment: Nope it isn't  nil. Cause I am validating self.txtEmail.text & self.txtPassword.text before that part

Comment: It might help to post more code.

Comment: There's a bug in your code. So how do you know they are not nil when you know there is a bug in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and got the crash when i try to print the dictionary.

i try to change the property like this to solve this crash

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *emailID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *password;
```

other code is as below

```
@synthesize emailID;
@synthesize password;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    emailID  = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.tfEmail.text];
    password = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.tfPassword.text];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : emailID, @"password" : password, @"device" : @"iOS"};

    NSLog(@"%@",params);


}
```

and it works !!